# object twitter is not a member of package org.apache.spark.streaming

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

```
import org.apache.spark.streaming.twitter._
```

gives the error

> object twitter is not a member of package org.apache.spark.streaming

I am trying to stream Twitter data using Spark. I am using SBT and have spent a lot of time to fix this. This is how my SBT looks like:

```
name := "stream-demo"
version := "1.0"
scalaVersion := "2.11.7"
val sparkVersion = "2.1.0"
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion,
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVersion,
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % sparkVersion)
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe" % "config" % "1.3.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.twitter4j" % "twitter4j-core" % "4.0.4"
libraryDependencies += "org.twitter4j" % "twitter4j-stream" % "4.0.4"
"1.5.2"
```

Any solution to fix this problem will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Twitter streaming dependency is missing. Add below dependency to your project.

SBT:

```
org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming-twitter_2.10" % 1.6.3
```

Maven:

```
 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-streaming-twitter_2.10 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-streaming-twitter_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.3</version>
        </dependency>
```